How can I downsize an RDS Postgres instance's disk?
I had an over-provisioned 4,999GB RDS instance with 4.6TB of disk free that I wanted to downsize to 499GB. This would save about $500/month in provisioned gp3 storage.
But I could not do it through the RDS portal! I also attempted to pg_dump and pg_restore this database, but it would cause too much downtime due to the size of the tables (>250GB). I also did not want to mess with configuring replication myself, because I don't know what I'm doing.
How can it be done?

I used the new (2023) homogeneous migration feature within Amazon Database Migration Service.
This process took about 40 hours to transfer a ~250GB database, using a db.m6g.xlarge instance type. I also upgraded from Postgres 12 to Postgres 16 at the same time.
Also: DMS successfully copied over our HSTORE and jsonb columns, without having to configure anything as you previously had to with DMS of the past.
DMS IAM role
DMS needs an IAM role to assume in order to run the migration. Configuring DMS's IAM role was the most annoying part of the DMS job creation process.
I created a new role with this "trust relationships" policy:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                    "dms.amazonaws.com",
                    "dms-data-migrations.amazonaws.com",
                    "dms.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {}
        }
    ]
}

Note that you need all 3 of these "Services" not just dms.amazonaws.com.
I went ahead and granted this role full admin permissions, because YOLO, but if you are worried about DMS owning you, you can restrict this to accessing secrets in Secrets Manager and DMS somehow.
Migration Steps:

Create new RDS instance with same instance type, but less disk as needed

Create the actual database you're migrating (CREATE DATABASE...)
Create the same users & permissions
I also used the same region and availability zone as the original db to prevent egress cost/latency.


Enable logical replication for source and target dbs:

Enable rds.logical_replication parameter in parameter groups
Add pglogical to shared_preload_libraries parameter
Set wal_sender_timeout parameter to 0 -- Replication lag will otherwise kill the migration prematurely
Restart instance
CREATE EXTENSION pglogical;


Create the "Migration Project" in Database Migration Service:

Create a DMS service role with this "trust relationships" policy (above)
Create "Data providers" - one for source, one for target DB. You have to create secrets in secrets manager for these credentials.
Create an "Instance profile", still not sure what this is.
Create the "Migration project", enabling "Full load" and "CDC" after. Definitely also set "Enable CloudWatch logs", otherwise you'll have no idea if it's doing anything and no way to debug failures.


Start & let it run for many hours

In our experience, a ton of data was copied over very quickly, then the rest of the tables trickled over during the next two days.
I used these two queries to monitor the progress on the destination -- one of them shows disk size, which will slowly increase as the table is replicated, and one shows the row count once the first load is complete.
Finally, I had to do a few things to complete the migration:

Put the site into readonly mode to prevent new writes
Update sequences to re-set nextval to the current values using this query -- these are apparently not updated as part of the migration
Switch site to new db & disable readonly

